# Determine constraint equations that a vector $b$ must satisfy in order to be in the image of the linear transformation $T :R^5 \to R^4$ defined by $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1\\1&1&2&0&2\\0&0&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

The coefficient matrix of $T$ is $A$.

Determine the constraint equation for $b$ in order for $b$ to be in the image of $T$.

What I have tried to do so far:

$im(A) = Span(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$ where $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ are columns of $A$.

So, $b \in Span(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$

Then, work out some kind of constraint equation from this, but I don't know how.

Comment: $b \in \operatorname{im}(A)$ if and only if $Ax = b$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R^5}$ in this case. You'll get the answer by writing $Ax=b$ explicitly in system of linear equations

Comment: @Captuna Thank you!